# How can i connect to a remote host using ssh?

Tags: ssh

Could anyone tell me the exact way to log in to remote host using ssh??I have been trying since quite some time, but couldn't do it.I have successfully created the keygen.But when i am trying to copy the public key to the remote host i get the following line line on the terminal - ssh: connect to host blr-ws-151 port 22: Connection timed out...Need some help badly

Comment: are you sure that you can connect on port 22 to the host you specify ? connection timed out indicates to me that you can't !

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable reply ManseUK..actually i am totally new to ssh ans using it for the very first time..could you please let me know how to check whether i can connect on port 22 to the remote host or not??..i have already installed ssh on it, but i don't know how to verify this port thing..many thanks

Comment: you should be able to `telnet` to that port on that host .... first check that the name resolves to an address using `ping <hostname>`

Comment: i am not able to connect to the remote host using telnet also..whenever i am trying to open a connection to that machine i receive the following line - Trying 192.168.2.75...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

Comment: the problem is with your connection - it seems that there is no direct connection between you and the server - either all traffic is blocked or a specific port - or the host you are connecting to isnt listening on that port - what OS is the server your connecting to ?

Comment: I have ubuntu 11.10 on both the machines..one thing i would like to add here is that i am able to ping the hosts from each other successfully

Comment: On the server you are trying to connect to run the following : `netstat -na` <- this will tell you which ports its listening on - check that 22 is listening on that port

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use:

```
ssh username@hostname
```

and you'll be prompted for a password. The hostname can be an IP address

```
man ssh
```

This Will give you the other options for using ssh.

Comment: I am unable to reach the remote host using ssh.Although i am able to ping that system with 0 loss